# Waiting for an HTTP Request to complete

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on `visual studio` for `Windows Phone` using `c#`. I am using a thread in which i need to call the function once the thread is completed, but my problem is there is an http call in my thread, so the thread goes to the completed stage before the http call ends. i need to end the thread only when that http call ends it. But now the thread ends after the http call is called, so how can I overcome this problem, thanks. here is my code

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        handle.MakeRequest(WidgetsCallBack, WidgetsErrorCallBack, 
                           DeviceInfo.DeviceId, ApplicationSettings.Apikey);
    });
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // function which i should call only after the thread is completed.
    // (http cll should also be ended)
}
```

Comment: please change all the mobile to phone, HUGE difference

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the http call you are making i believe that you are making an asychronous one. So, in case you would like to run the http call in a different thread then you can just use any of the many async methods (e.g. [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)). So, you don't need a thread to achieve that. Does this help?

**Updated to provide sample code based on the comment below:**

So, instead of a worker, i would use a WebClient object and call a URL in an asynchronous manner:

```
// Creating the client object:
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

// Registering a handler to the async request completed event. The Handler method is HandleRequest and is wrapped:
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(HandleRequest);

// Setting some header information (just to illustrate how to do it):
wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

// Making the actual call to a given URL:
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"));
```

And the definition of the handler method:

```
void HandleRequest(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
         // Handle e.Result as there are no issues:
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i am making an asynchronous thread. i sae the link provided can u please explain me in detail how can i use it here ??